# Reset Activity Calibration on Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

I went for a jog with my Apple Watch and iPhone in order to calibrate my Apple Watch activity monitoring. Annoyingly, I must've chosen the Outdoor Walk activity and not Outdoor Run. Where I used to get excercise minutes for brisk walks, I no longer do.

Is there anyway to reset the calibration so that I can do it again?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option: In running trails with my Apple Watch and iPhone the calibration is not correct. Miles is not correct because of switch backs and trees. What I do is go to the Watch app on my iPhone, Tap the My Watch tab then tap Privacy > Motion & Fitness > Reset Calibration Data. This erases the calibration and I can start over with a clean slate. You do not have to reset everything using this method.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize this option was there.

Answer (score 2):

Unpairing and re-pairing your WATCH used to reset your calibration data. However, as of watchOS 2.x, this is [no longer the case](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204518), as that data now gets backed up to your iPhone.

It seems you are left with three options:

1. Take your WATCH on a few walks with the Workout app, hoping it eventually [recalibrates](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204516) itself.
2. Reset your WATCH as new by going into the **Settings** app on your WATCH.
3. Unpair your WATCH and perform an **un**encrypted backup of your iPhone to iTunes. Then restore your iPhone from backup, and pair your WATCH once again. You will lose all health data, passwords, etc. from your iPhone as well.

Seems #2 would be the most straightforward approach, although you could try #1 for a while and see if that’s enough.

I added #3 for completeness’s sake only